# Google Adsense ads not showing on Windows and Blackberry Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, blackberry, adsense

Here is the link of the site:

Here is the google Adsense Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1334021877048856";
     google_ad_slot = "5550178046";
     google_ad_width = 320;
     google_ad_height = 50;
</script>
<script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It works perfectly fine in all other mobile browsers. I tried in desktop version it does work fine but if you inject Window's Phone browser user agent in Firefox to test Ads doesn't show up even on desktop browser.

I read through some forums which says it's blocked by either google or microsoft still not sure.

here are the links for one the forums:

http://www.amitbhawani.com/blog/google-adsense-ads-windows-phone/

Any help would be great-full.

Comment: I changed your tag from `windows-mobile` to `windows-phone-7`. That should get you in touch with the right group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall that in the past year or so, Google blocked a YouTube app on the Windows Phone based on the claim that:

> Microsoft has not made the browser upgrades necessary to enable a
>   fully-featured YouTube experience, and has instead re-released a
>   YouTube app that violates our Terms of Service."

This quote supports the browser incomaptibility theory.  Based on the forum post that you linked to and through your tests with the user agent, I don't think there's a solution to getting Adsense working on the Windows Phone 7 browser unfortunately.

[EDIT] It seems like Blackberry has their own [advertising service](http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_services/advertising.html) which means that they probably block google adsense from running so that developers use their service.

Comment: what about blackberry ?

Comment: Are you seeing issues with OS 7.1 or with 10?